# How to apply a Sea mask over a NetCDF file using CDO

Tags: mask, netcdf4, cdo-climate, topography

Let's say I have made a `netCDF` file, which has a lot of zeros. I want to apply a sea mask to the data, such that only the regions in the sea are really masked and the data on the land is retained.

The data that I have has a lot of zeros on land (which is correct), but also has a lot of zeros in the sea (which is not correct).

I could have used `cdo setmissval,nan input.nc output.nc` but that would have also changed the value on the land to `NaN`.

Does someone have any (good) solution to that?

Comment: Can you provide some example data? I assume it is not easy to do with one-liner, but in any case, it would already help if you have also the seamask/landmask data available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a NetCDF file with data masked to retain land points only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058260/create-a-netcdf-file-with-data-masked-to-retain-land-points-only)

Comment: @Ep1c1aN, I know I was late, but did the answer below help?

Comment: Yes, it did (Solution 1). I did not try Solution 2 though, but I suppose it would be more precise since it is at 1km resolution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already posed here:  [Create a NetCDF file with data masked to retain land points only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058260/create-a-netcdf-file-with-data-masked-to-retain-land-points-only)

### Solution  1:

So basically you can build a land-sea mask using the built in topography function, and then set all the sea points to missing:

```
cdo -f nc setctomiss,0 -gtc,0 -remapcon,your_data_file.nc -topo seamask.nc
```

- **topo** : generates a topography file
- **remapcon** : remaps it to your input
  file resolution
- **gtc**,0 : sets to 1 for all topographical points above
  sea level, 0 otherwise
- **setctomiss**: the zeros for the sea points are
  converted to "missing"

You can now use this to mask your datafile:

```
cdo mul your_data_file.nc seamask.nc masked_datafile.nc
```

However, in some circumstances I have found that the remapping process leaves traces of "ocean" data around the edges, in this case to be safer you can use the second method:

### Solution 2:

Download the netcdf data file for "distance to ocean" at 1km resolution from this thredds server: https://pae-paha.pacioos.hawaii.edu/thredds/ncss/dist2coast_1deg_land/dataset.html

Then you can mask out any points within a certain distance of the ocean to play it safe, at the expense of possibly masking out a small amount of land data.

I remapped the distance file to the target resolution first:

```
cdo remapbil,your_data.nc distance.nc remap_dist.nc
```

then mask (e.g. in this case all points within 5km of the coast, sea points are already "missing" in this file) and multiply

```
cdo mul your_data.nc -gtc,5 remap_dist.nc masked_data.nc
```

As said, this is a little safer, a little more longwinded, but may mask some land data.